# Overflow when attempting to compute ratio of exponential functions

Tags: floating-point, floating-accuracy

I'm trying to compute pointwise values of the function `sinh(k-k*x)/sinh(k)`, where `k=1e4` and `x` takes on values between 0 and 1. This function is essentially a sum of exponential functions. Of course, attempting to compute `exp(1e4)` results in overflow errors. However, the actual function above only takes on values between 0 and 1, so I'm wondering if there is a clever way that I can compute the function for arbitrary values of `x` in the specified range.

The function can be expanded into the form

```
exp(k-k*x)/(exp(k)-exp(-k)) - exp(k*x-k)/(exp(k)-exp(-k))
```

I thought to try taking logarithms first and seeing if anything simplifies, but I couldn't see a way through. Does anyone have advice for me on how to deal with this issue? I'm working in Python right now but I think the language doesn't matter so much here.

Comment: This would be a good question for https://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @RobertBaron I would go for [Computational Science SE](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/), but I am biased :)

Answer (score 1):

If you take `y=1-x`, you are trying to evaluate this

```
(e^(ky)-e^(-ky)) / (e^k - e^(-k))
```

That is

```
e^(ky) * (1 - e^(-2ky)) / (e^k * (1 - e^(-2k)))
```

Then

```
e^(ky)/e^k = (e^k)^y * (e^k)^(-1) = (e^k)^(y-1) = e^(k(y-1)) = e^(-kx)
```

The other factor `(1 - e^(-2ky)) / (1 - e^(-2k))` can be evaluated without overflow.